# How to make this search code filter results only after clicking the button

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I found this code on codepen and made some changes in it. I am trying to filter the results after clicking the search button. But the point is that now it's filtering instantly when you type in the search box.

Here is the code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: [2],
        search: '',
        items: [{
                action: '15 min',
                headline: 'Brunch this weekend?',
                title: 'Ali Connors',
                subtitle: "I'll be in your neighborhood doing errands this weekend. Do you want to hang out?"
            },
            {
                action: '2 hr',
                headline: 'Summer BBQ',
                title: 'me, Scrott, Jennifer',
                subtitle: "Wish I could come, but I'm out of town this weekend."
            },
            {
                action: '6 hr',
                headline: 'Oui oui',
                title: 'Sandra Adams',
                subtitle: 'Do you have Paris recommendations? Have you ever been?'
            },
            {
                action: '12 hr',
                headline: 'Birthday gift',
                title: 'Trevor Hansen',
                subtitle: 'Have any ideas about what we should get Heidi for her birthday?'
            },
            {
                action: '18hr',
                headline: 'Recipe to try',
                title: 'Britta Holt',
                subtitle: 'We should eat this: Grate, Squash, Corn, and tomatillo Tacos.'
            }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        filteredItems() {
            return _.orderBy(this.items.filter(item => {
              if(!this.search) return this.items;
                return (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                    item.action.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())   ||
                    item.headline.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                    item.subtitle.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()));
            }), 'headline');
        }
    },
    methods: {
      clearSearch () {
        this.search="";
      },
        toggle(index) {
            const i = this.selected.indexOf(index)

            if (i > -1) {
                this.selected.splice(i, 1)
            } else {
                this.selected.push(index)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I will share complete code in the comment where you can see a complete working example. How can this search filter only after clicking the search button?

Comment: Here is the full example:
https://codepen.io/artyombaykov/pen/QzBxJE?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's filtering instantly when you type in the search box is because `filteredItems` is a computed property which means it's gonna run every time the value of `search` changes which is every time you type a new character.

To filter the items only after the button is clicked, remove `filteredItems` from `computed` and create a `filterItems` function under your `methods` and attach that handler to the button's click event.

```
methods: {
  filterItems() {
    this.filteredItems = _.orderBy(
      this.items.filter(item => {
        if (!this.search) return this.items;
        return (
          item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          item.action.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          item.headline.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          item.subtitle.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );
      }),
      "headline"
    );
  } 
}
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" @click="filterItems">Search</button>
```

> Notice that I assigned the result of the function to `filteredItems`
>   which is a new property that you should add to your `data` object.

The reason is that your `filterItems` function should not mutate the original `items` but create a new array when it executes otherwise it would cause a bug if you mutate the original items and try filtering it again.

So in your `data` object, add `filteredItems` which will have the initial value equal to the `items` since it's not filtered yet when your app is mounted.

```
const items = [];

new Vue({
  data: {
    filteredItems: items,
    items: items
  }
})
```

See [working implementation](https://codepen.io/analizapandac/pen/QzJQGZ?editors=1010).

*Note that I also call `filterItems()` when you clear your search so that it resets the data but you can just remove it from `clearSearch()` if you don't want that behaviour.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One more question. If there will be pagination or infinite scrolling, then will it filter through the all results or will filter just first page results?

Comment: It will only filter the currently stored `items`, the current page's items.

Comment: Is it generally supported to filter through the whole list instead of a first page only by using filters? I am asking it because we have a similar case in Angular and it's interesting if such a filter can support filtering through the whole list instead.

Comment: If you use pagination under the current implementation, it will filter the items under the current page only and not the whole list, unless of course, you run an API request that will return the filtered data instead of just looping through your currently stored items.

Comment: In the other example, it gets to get all users from backend through the API and then in the front, we use a filter like this and want to add pagination. So from the backend, it gets a full list of users.

Comment: If you have the full list of data, then yes the filter would work on the whole list even with pagination. I haven't implemented pagination on the frontend though since mostly I just rely on the backend to provide me the paginated results so I don't know how this would affect the behaviour.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot :)